# How to get the header of the parent node of a selected TreeViewItem?

Tags: .net, wpf, data-binding, treeview

I have this TreeView:

```
Main Node Header="Main"
   Sub Node Header="Sub1"
      Final Node Header="Item1"
      Final Node Header="Item2"
   Sub Node Header="Sub 2"
      Final Node Header="Item1"
      Final Node Header="Item2"
```

I have two textboxes that are bound to this TreeView. One has its Text property bound to the TreeView's SelectedItem property and works OK.

The other TextBox I want to bind to the Header text of the Sub Node directly above the selected Item.

How do I reference it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way would be to manifest the child/parent relationship in your view models and have your bindings work against the view model objects rather than the view objects.

An alternative would be to write a value converter that looks up the parent `TreeViewItem` for a given `TreeViewItem` and bind to `SelectedItem` using that converter.

Comment: Thanks! In the viewmodel the Parents know about their Children, but not the other way around. All I can work with is the SelectionChanged (of the TreeView) and Selected ( of the TreeViewItem) events. The same Child can appear several times in the TreeView with different parent nodes. How can I use the data available through these events to look up the parent of the currently selected item?

Comment: All right, I give in... I adapted the viewmodel to make this work. Do I get good grades now? ;-)